# Django import export extended User

Tags: django, django-users, django-import-export

I'm trying to use Django import-export to import data in my app.
Even with the documentation, I can't make it work for my "Proprietaire" Model, which is extending Django's user model. Here my models:

```
class Proprietaire(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    adresse = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    telephone_regex = RegexValidator(
        regex="[0-9]{10}", message="Veuillez entrer un numéro de téléphone valide."
    )
    telephone = models.CharField(validators=[telephone_regex], max_length=10)
    date_inscription = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

The user import seems to be working fine but then I don't know how to import my `Proprietaire`s and link them to my `User`s. After reading the documentation, I tried something like this in my admin file:

```
class ProprietaireResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Proprietaire
        fields = ('user__username','telephone','adresse')
        import_id_fields = ('user__username')


@admin.register(Proprietaire)
class ProprietaireAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = ProprietaireResource

admin.site.unregister(User)

@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    pass
```

But whatever I try (without `import_id_fields` or without `fields`, or with `adrresse` as `import_id_fields`), I keep getting errors like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\perre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 500, in import_row
instance, new = self.get_or_init_instance(instance_loader, row)
File "C:\Users\perre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 277, in get_or_init_instance
instance = self.get_instance(instance_loader, row)
File "C:\Users\perre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 265, in get_instance
import_id_fields = [
File "C:\Users\perre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 266, in <listcomp>
self.fields[f] for f in self.get_import_id_fields()
KeyError: 'a'
```

I don't understand what's happening here.

For information, I'm trying to use the same file to import `User` and `Proprietaire` (I don't think that should be a problem); here's an example of a line I'm trying to import:

Headers : id,first_name,last_name,user__username,username,email,is_active,adresse,telephone
Line : ,Clémentine,PerreautBis,clementine.perreautbis,clementine.perreautbis,example@test.fr,0,25 rue du Paradis 69003 Lyon,0203040506

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem.
As it was important for me to keep it all in one file (the end user is supposed to fill the import files and I wanted to keep it as simple as possible for them) and I didn't think it was the problem, I looked up the widget part only to see if it would make a difference.
And it did! After reading the following documentation: https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_widgets.html, my code looked like this:

```
class ProprietaireResource(ModelResource):
    user = Field(column_name='user', attribute='user', widget=ForeignKeyWidget(User, 'username'))
    class Meta:
        model = Proprietaire
        fields = ('id','user','adresse','telephone')
```

I renamed my column "user__username" as "user" and everything worked like expected :)
Thanks for the advice about the ForeignKeyWidget.

Answer (score 0):

Add "," after username in `import_id_fields = ('user__username')`

Instead of

```
import_id_fields = ('user__username')
```

Try

```
import_id_fields = ('user__username', )
```

('user__username') is not an iterable, but a string. However, if you add a comma it will be a tuple and hence an iterable.

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion would be to split `User` and `Proprietaire` into separate files, then import `User` first and link to it in the `Proprietaire` using [ForeignKeyWidget](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_widgets.html#import_export.widgets.ForeignKeyWidget). You do say that there is a User import, so you might be doing this already.  This would be the standard way of working with the framework and it should be fairly straightforward.

If you cannot do this, and need to have both `User` and `Proprietaire` in the same csv file, then I think you will have to create a sub-class of `Resource` and override the [`save_instance()`](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_resources.html#import_export.resources.Resource.save_instance) method to handle extracting the User fields and creating / updating before the `Proprietaire` model instance is saved.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't understand why I should split my file. I'm not trying to import both User and Proprietaire at the same time. I use the file a first time to import User (wich only takes the colums for the User and works fine) and then I want to use the same file to import Proprietaire, expecting it to read only the columns for this model.
But anyway, I don't think using the same file changes anything. If i seperate them the result would be the same as the problem seems to be my usage of ForeignKey. Do you thinf using  ForeignKeyWidget would resolve that?

Comment: Based on what you've said, I think having two separate files is the way to go, as it will make it easier to manage the process.   Two files means two models, and you can define the resources appropriately.  That's where the ForeignKeyWidget helps, because it refers to a User instance from a Proprietaire file.  Doing it all in one file will involve overriding and writing custom code as I suggested in my answer.